# Can I compute the trajectory in a maze if I know the walls?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Let's assume that I have a mouse in a maze and the mouse need to find the exit.

I know where the exit is and where my position is. I also know the position of the walls.

How can I compute the trajectory for the path in the maze? What method should I use?

Comment: You want to perform this task using machine-learning? Do you want the mouse to *learn* how to find a path to the exit ?

Comment: @OlivierRoche I don't know if machine-learning is the right method. Not learn the mouse find the path. I want to only find the trajectory (the line path) from the mouse to the exit. The shortest way and the best way. Without collision of the walls.

Comment: Are the movements required to be either horizontal or vertical? Same question for the walls.

Comment: @OlivierRoche In small scale yes. I was thinking that the whole maze is a grid of tiny tiny pixels.

Comment: Lastly, are the movements of the mouse discrete?

Comment: @OlivierRoche Not in real life. But in computing, it can be described as discrete steps if they are small. Do you think Q-learning is the right method to use here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104259/discussion-between-olivier-roche-and-daniel-martensson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each position in the labyrinth, the mouse has at most four directions it can move toward (North, West, South, East).  You can use a brute-force approach and compute the following tree recursively. Each node of the tree is labeled by a word, say $w$, on the alphabet $\{N, W, S, E\}$ that corresponds to a path from the starting position. Using this path, you can recover the corresponding position of the mouse : say mouse started at coordinates $(x, y)$, then it has now coordinates $(x + n_E - n_W, y + n_N - n_S)$ where $n_E$ is the number of $E$s in $w$, etc.

- The root of the tree is the empty word $\epsilon$.
- If a node corresponds to the exit, no child is added to it (the mouse found an exit).
- If a node labeled by $w$ doesn't correspond to the exit, add a child for each legal step that the mouse can make in this position and that doesn't lead to a position that has already been visited along the path $w$.

In the end, all possible path to exit are leaves of this tree (but beware, some leaves correspond to dead ends).

Comment: Found the better solution. A* algorthm.